# Multiplication/Division in Galois Field (2^8)

Tags: finite-field

I'm attempting to implement multiplication and division in $GF(2^8)$ using log and exponential tables. I'm using the exponent of 3 as my generator, using instructions from [here](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/laws/FFM.html).

However I'm having trouble getting the expected answer for some of these trivial multiplications.

For $2 · 4$ this works:

$$ \begin{align*}
 \log_3(2) &= 25 \\
 \log_3(4) &= 50 \\
    25 + 50 &= 75 \\
 \exp_3(75) &= 8 \Rightarrow \text{ expected answer}
\end{align*}$$

However for $7 · 11$ this breaks down:

$$\begin{align*}
    \log_3(7) &= 198 \\
    \log_3(11) &= 104 \\
    198 + 104 &= 302. \\
\text{Mod it by 255, gives us 47.}\\
    \exp_3(47) &= 49
\end{align*}$$
instead of the expected 77.

From what I understand, we use modulus 255 because the 3 generator 'wraps around' on the 255th power (so the pattern repeats after that) thus we only need 0~254. Even if I'm wrong in this, $302 \bmod 256$ still doesn't give us $70$, where $\exp_3(70) = 77$ (the expected answer)

My observation for both multiplication and division is that it works fine until the result of addition/subtraction goes out of range of 0~255.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In GF(2<sup>8</sup>), 7 × 11 = 49.  The discrete logarithm trick works just fine.

Your mistake is in assuming that [Galois field multiplication](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/galois-fields-in-cryptography/2718#2718) works the same way as normal integer multiplication.  In prime-order fields this actually *is* more or less the case, except that you need to reduce the result modulo the order of the field, but in fields of non-prime order the multiplication rules are different.

Let's do 7 × 11, for example.  Noting that 7 = 111<sub>2</sub> and 11 = 1011<sub>2</sub>, we can calculate 7 × 11 in binary as:

```
    111 ×
   1011 =
   ------
    111 +
   1110 +
 111000 =
 --------
```

So far, everything works the same as in ordinary integer multiplication.  But whereas in the integers we'd propagate carries while doing the addition, and thus end up with

111<sub>2</sub> + 1110<sub>2</sub> + 111000<sub>2</sub> = 10101<sub>2</sub> + 111000<sub>2</sub> = 1001101<sub>2</sub> = 77,

in GF(2<sup>*n*</sup>) addition is done bitwise *without* carries (i.e. GF(2<sup>*n*</sup>) addition is the same as bitwise XOR), and thus we get

111<sub>2</sub> + 1110<sub>2</sub> + 111000<sub>2</sub> = 1001<sub>2</sub> + 111000<sub>2</sub> = 110001<sub>2</sub> = 49.

(Of course, if the result exceeded the group order, we'd also have to reduce it modulo the reduction polynomial, but in this case that doesn't happen for *n* ≥ 7.)

Comment: what about division for the same??

Comment: @Kaushal28: Using discrete logarithms, division works exactly the same as multiplication, except that you subtract the logarithms instead of adding them: $\log(a/b) = \log(a) - \log(b)$. AFAIK, the easiest way to do division in a finite field *without* logarithms is to first compute the inverse of the divisor (e.g. using the extended Euclidean algorithm, as shown at the end of [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12962)) and then multiply that with the dividend.