# Multiplicative inverse in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$?

Tags: aes, finite-field

I know how to do multiplication over ${\rm GF}(2^8)$:

```
uint8_t  gmul(uint8_t  a, uint8_t  b)
{
    uint8_t p=0;
    uint8_t carry;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if(b & 1)
            p ^=a;
        carry = a & 0x80;
        a = a<<1;
        if(carry)
            a^=0x1b;
        b = b>>1;
    }
    return p;
}
```

So, I tried to create a ${\rm GF}(2^8)$ multiplication table using this code.
I've given below the values in the 3rd row of the table, but I don't think they're correct:

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
0
1
2   0  2  4  6  8  A  C  E  10 12 14 16 18 1A 1C 1E 
3
.
.
E
F
```

I don't know what went wrong. I built the table by multiplying the values in the first row with those in the first column. 
E.g. in the third row, I multiplied 2 × 0, 2 × 1, …, 2 × E, 2 × F.

How can I create a multiplication table for arithmetic in ${\rm GF}(2^8)$?

---

Also, how can I find the multiplicative inverse of a number in ${\rm GF}(2^8)$?

For example, how can I determine that the inverse of 95 is 8A?  I tried to do this using the multiplication table above, but when I took 9th row and the 5th column in the multiplication table I got 2D, not 8A.

Answer (score 18):

The standard method for doing multiplication (and multiplicative inverses) in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$ is using a log and antilog table.  Each table takes up only 255 bytes; hence it is much smaller than a full $256 \times 256$ multiplication table, and it is much faster than the multiplication procedure you give above.

To create such tables, we need to pick a generator $g$; that is a field element such that $g^i$ is all 255 nonzero elements for $0 \le i < 255$ (where $g^i$ is what you would expect; $g$ multiplied by itself $i$ time).  Such an element always exists, and (IIRC) $g=3$ happens to be a generator in the field representation you are using.

Now, the antilog table is defined as:

$${\rm antilog}(i) = g^i$$

This table has 255 elements, and can be easily built using your multiplication procedure.  You may want to extend it farther (as discussed below); it just continues in the obvious way (and it just repeats itself).

The log table is defined as its inverse, that is:

$$\log(\operatorname{antilog}(i)) = i$$

This table also has 255 elements (but is indexed from 1 to 255), and can be built using the antilog table we already have, or just initialized at the same time:

```
uint8_t log_table[256], antilog[255];
const uint8_t g = 3;

void init_log_table(void)
{
    log_table[0] = 0;  /* dummy value */
    for (int i = 0, x = 1; i < 255; x = gmul(x, g), i++) {
        log_table[x] = i;
        antilog[i] = x;
    }
}
```

Once we have those two, we can do multiplication by:

```
uint8_t gmul_table(uint8_t a, uint8_t b)
{
    if (a == 0 || b == 0) return 0;

    uint8_t x = log_table[a];
    uint8_t y = log_table[b];
    uint8_t log_mult = (x + y) % 255;

    return antilog[log_mult];
}
```

This works because, if $a = g^x$ and $b = g^y$, then $a \times b = g^x \times g^y = g^{x+y} = g^{(x+y) \bmod 255}$

As you can see, that should be considerably more efficient than your original algorithm; you can omit the `% 255` operation by extending the antilog table for 255 more elements.

We can also use those tables to compute multiplicative inverses:

```
uint8_t ginv_table(uint8_t a)
{
    if (a == 0) return 0;       /* as needed in the context of AES */

    uint8_t x = log_table[a];   /* x       is in range [0..255] */
    uint8_t log_inv = 255 - x;  /* log_inv is in range [0..255] */

    return antilog[log_inv];
}
```

You can also compute inverses using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm (which can be adapted to work in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$; however it's considerably more work than two table lookups.

Here is how that algorithm would look like:

```
uint8_t ginv(uint8_t x)
{
    uint16_t u1 = 0, u3 = 0x11b, v1 = 1, v3 = x;

    while (v3 != 0) {
        uint16_t t1 = u1, t3 = u3;
        int8_t q = bitlength(u3) - bitlength(v3);

        if (q >= 0) {
            t1 ^= v1 << q;
            t3 ^= v3 << q;
        }
        u1 = v1; u3 = v3;
        v1 = t1; v3 = t3;
    }

    if (u1 >= 0x100) u1 ^= 0x11b;

    return u1;
}
```

where `bitlength(x)` returns the position of the most significant 1 bit of `x` (i.e. the smallest number `y` such that `(1 << y) - 1 >= x`).

Comment: i included "#include<math.h>" then too i get the following error- undefined reference to `antilog'.  can you explain(with code)how to compute using euclidean algorithm. i know the extended euclidean alogorithm, but don't know how to implement in binaries?

Comment: Actually, log and antilog are tables that you build (or initialize); they're uint8_t log[255], antilog[255];  (and, come to think about it, in C, log isn't the best name; it conflicts with the log() function within math.h).  You initialize those tables as above (possibly using your multiplication routine to generate the initial antilog entries)

Comment: k will do, but can you show me code using extended euclidean algorithm to show multiplicative inverse?

Comment: hot to create antilog(log_inv) function? you said to create uint8_t log[255] which is an array,then how will antilog(log_inv)call will work? how to implement it? if any other ways are there please show me

Comment: I just edited your generally excellent answer to add some explicit code for building the log and antilog tables; please do revert or edit it if you don't like my changes. Also, just for completeness, [here's a quick little test program](http://ideone.com/D5VBpN) showing that this code indeed works, and that the table-based implementations give the same results as the non-table-based ones.

Comment: @poncho: I'm puzzled by the use of `q = numbits(z)` , defined as the _number of bits set_ in `z`(for example, `q=1` for `z=8`); can you explain?

Comment: @fgrieu: well, we're trying to figure out how many bits to shift v3 left so that `v3<<q` cancels out the msbit of `u3`.  x is u3 will all the bits to the right of the msbit set (so if u3 = 0x12, then x = 0x1f); similarly y is v3 with all the bits to the right of the msbit set.  Because of this, z will consist of those bits where there's a bit set to the left in u3, but not in v3.  Hence, the number of such bits is the number of bits we need to shift v3 left.

Comment: BTW, at least on some architectures it could be useful to replace the `% 255` in `gmul_table()` with the ["digital root"](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) `log_mult = (log_mult >> 8) + (log_mult & 0xFF)`. It won't give exactly the same results as `% 255`, since it won't map 255 to 0 (but it *will* correctly map 256 to 1, 257 to 2, etc.), but that's easily handled by adding a single extra entry to the `antilog[]` table. Basically, compared to just extending the table, it saves 1/4 kB at the cost of 1-3 simple operations (shift, mask & add, or possibly just a single 8-bit add-with-carry).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: not a bad suggestion...

Comment: Thanks for the reply to @fgrieu's comment above. To be honest, the bit fiddling and counting confused me too, but your explanation made it clear. Based on it, I took the liberty of rewriting your `ginv()` code to use a `bitlength()` function/macro instead, hopefully making the actual algorithm clearer (and probably faster too, at least on platforms that have a built-in [bit length / leading zero count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) instruction). And yes, [I checked that it still works.](http://ideone.com/J4gCaw)

Comment: @poncho If we are using GCC or Clang compiler, then the fastest method to calculate ```bitlength(x)``` would be to use ```#define bitlength(x) (32 - __builtin_clz(x)) ``` , if $x > 0$ ....

Answer (score 6):

The question's `gmul` code correctly computes $A*B$ with each of $A$ and $B$ any of the $256$ elements of $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$. But notice that the multiplication table shown has $16\times16$ entries, a very small subset of the full table with $256\times256$ entries.

One way to compute the multiplicative inverse $A^{-1}$ is as $B=A^{254}$, which works because $A*B=A*A^{254}=A^{255}=1$ since the order of the multiplicative subgroup is $2^8-1=255$.

```
/* modular inverse, computing a^^254 using exponentiation by squaring */ 
uint8_t ginv(uint8_t a) {
    uint8_t j, b = a;
    for (j = 14; --j;)              /* for j from 13 downto 1 */
        b = gmul(b, j&1 ? b : a);   /* alternatively square and multiply */
    return b;
}
```

This can be reduced from 13 to 11 field multiplications with an addition chain, code in this [**Try It Online!**](https://tio.run/##rVXbcpswEH3nK3bcaQoxDhcbxxNsd/rQ9gP62IaOwLItByQKosXTSX/dXUGEL5k0iafM2KDdc85Ku8uSDFZJsts5lxBXLF3Ah49fgPGftCgpSBKnFAZQUgprKfPyxnGSYptLcVVKktzROlkTvqJXicgc4oxcb@Q6QRDApWMYbxhP0mpBYVrKBePyaj03DAzz@ZPpRxMLsiqVLE9ZQiQT3IZcpFsuMkZSqKNJv45G@Bv2676n5JCYCI5RuRxIllEQHDJRSmBZntKMctnIlDb8qJiksCToQ16FkSffJawwnKkXQGzonmMLfhuAl7bkMANzYMYXnmVdkLDx5RChkSgPush8fo0@t/ZiKzLJdKqQaDfj@dyzFO@1LP8s1vAs1ugsVnAWa3zAKqisCg7IeY513bCsKA@N@6ZnMrGoUlLoxrSxF7K8koyvgESRH4ygKtVC8HQLntdU@zVdc9QpGKTrFHLaHDEeuuklYhMrBAwA4Cv6ISjZg2INGmqQvjqlxE40aPwkKO6UPP8UlOxBWskLXqDkj14AGk3@AdLhxsPnlTz/6dORPehag3S7qOtYSdUbQW1rtFOrnVRiqTsE50DbESvKaUGkKMCt3eEBAtfL8Wnd5Vc/GN@G3QZR/5Gy4vwUbAGrJrQ01eK0TRiezLNho25hK8SA8AVaSEGPtBRtKQozDLVIc@JmN@wWBTZhZ2U6YcxuzmMduJZgstlsY0FcUHIXPmyf8kUJGZWHqd9olY3dZOFApQ27UWFZa7039nZX2d3woII6Qe9KjCSLrToJuMBK/OtKlBeYFZBr@iiZeAf5S0BGOJapScfxZ0Oor4ZiZ4Txo0wr48MWVfbYzA3ZFKsX9vvM6s7ThF6aYP5hOFMCeA@9t65fQw9u2qdvvGe3rzzrplvL6aHrwaIrbf3HeKq4x4PRVdNut/sL), also illustrating a typically constant-time and faster `gmul`.

---

As explained in [poncho's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12962/555), there are more efficient ways to perform multiplication, and inverse, using two tables for log and antilog; and the inverse can also be built using the extended Euclidean algorithm. Beware that both lead to typically non-constant-time code, which can make an implementation vulnerable to timing attack.

As explained in [Dmitry Khovratovich's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12958/555), one could find the inverse of any non-zero $A$ by systematically looking for which $B$ it holds that $A*B=1$, which will require attempting at worse $255$ non-zero values of $B$. This is OK for building the table of inverses once for all, but that can be optimized to:

```
/* build table of inverses, using generator 0x03 of inverse 0xf6 */
uint8_t ginvt[256];          /* table of inverses */
void gbuildt(void) {
    uint8_t i = 1, j = 1;   /* i and j are inverses */
    for(;;) {               /* loop */
        ginvt[i] = j;
        i = gmul(i, 0x03);
        if (i==j) break;    /* ends met */
        j = gmul(j, 0xf6);
        ginvt[j] = i;
    }
    ginvt[0] = 0;           /* table's entry for 0 is 0 */
}
```

This uses a known generator `0x03` and its inverse `0xf6`. It builds their respective powers until they meet. The loop is performed 127 times, for a total of 255 field multiplications. [**Try It Online!**](https://tio.run/##rVXbcpswEH3nK3bcaQoxDhcbxxNsd/rQ9gP62IaOwLItByQKosXTSX/dXUGEL5k0iafM2KDdc85Ku8uSDFZJsts5lxBXLF3Ah49fgPGftCgpSBKnFAZQUgprKfPyxnGSYptLcVVKktzROlkTvqJXicgc4oxcb@Q6QRDApWMYbxhP0mpBYVrKBePyaj03DAzz@ZPpRxMLsiqVLE9ZQiQT3IZcpFsuMkZSqKNJv45G@Bv2676n5JCYCI5RuRxIllEQHDJRSmBZntKMctnIlDb8qJiksCToQ16FkSffJawwnKkXQGzonmMLfhuAl7bkMANzYMYXnmVdkLDx5RChkSgPush8fo0@t/ZiKzLJdKqQaDfj@dyzFO@1LP8s1vAs1ugsVnAWa3zAKqisCg7IeY513bCsKA@N@6ZnMrGoUlLoxrSxF7K8koyvgESRH4ygKtVC8HQLntdU@zVdc9QpGKTrFHLaHDEeuuklYhMrBAwA4Cv6ISjZg2INGmqQvjqlxE40aPwkKO6UPP8UlOxBWskLXqDkj14AGk3@AdLhxsPnlTz/6dORPehag3S7qOtYSdUbQW1rtFOrnVRiqTsE50DbESvKaUGkKMCt3eEBAtfL8Wnd5Vc/GN@G3QZR/5Gy4vwUbAGrJrQ01eK0TRiezLNho25hK8SA8AVaSEGPtBRtKQozDLVIc@JmN@wWBTZhZ2U6YcxuzmMduJZgstlsY0FcUHIXPmyf8kUJGZWHqd9olY3dZOFApQ27UWFZa7039nZX2d3woII6Qe9KjCSLrToJuMBK/OtKlBeYFZBr@iiZeAf5S0BGOJapScfxZ0Oor4ZiZ4Txo0wr48MWVfbYzA3ZFKsX9vvM6s7ThF6aYP5hOFMCeA@9t65fQw9u2qdvvGe3rzzrplvL6aHrwaIrbf3HeKq4x4PRVdNut/sL)

Notice that the reduction binary polynomial $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ is irreducible (as it must be) but not primitive, thus `0x02` is not a generator (which inverse is just the reduction polynomial `0x11b` right-shifted by one).

---

In the general case of $\operatorname{GF(2^n)}$, the cost of building the table by the above technique is asymptotically a single field multiplication and assignment per entry in the table, including the cost of finding a generator and it's inverse, as follows:

- We can test if an element $g$ is a generator by checking $g^{(2^n-1)/p}\ne1$ (computable using exponentiation by squaring with less than $2n$ field multiplications) for each prime $p$ dividing $2^n-1$ (starting with the lowest $p$ for efficiency). The cost of factoring $2^n-1$ is negligible since we have sub-exponential factoring algorithms, and especially good ones for Mersenne numbers. We know [these factorizations](http://oeis.org/A001265/a001265_1.txt) for all $n<929$.
- Each $g$ tested has probability $>1/2$ to be a generator, so we test less than two $g$ on average, and conjecturally less than $2+\log_2 n$ when we try $g$ per the sequence of binary irreducible polynomials ([OEIS A014580](https://oeis.org/A014580)), which first terms are $\mathtt{02_h}$, $\mathtt{03_h}$, $\mathtt{07_h}$, $\mathtt{0b_h}$, $\mathtt{0d_h}$, $\mathtt{13_h}$, $\mathtt{19_h}$, $\mathtt{1f_h}$…
- When we get $g$, it's inverse can be found as $g^{2^n-2}$, with less than $2n$ field multiplications.

The technique could be useful e.g. to build a 16 GiB table of inverses in $\operatorname{GF}(2^{32})$ (or S-table based on that), without additionally requiring the log and antilog tables of [poncho's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12962/555), which eat an additional 32 GiB.

Answer (score 4):

The multiplication table has $2^8 = 256$ rows and columns. You are doing the multiplication right, but you have not filled the entire third row yet (there must be 256 elements).

To find the inverse of $A$, you find $B$ such that $A*B = 1$ in your multiplication table (there are other algorithms for inversion, but you might not need them for such a small field).

Comment: can you give any of the inversion algorithm?

Comment: inverse of 95 is 8A. but when i took 9th row and 5th column in multiplication table i got 2D. So A*B !=1. then how to fidn out inverse of 95?

Comment: You have a multiplication table. And you look for entries $9$ and $5$. That means you compute a value $9\cdot 5= 2D$ (or 45 in decimal). This has nothing to do with the inverse of $95$. If you have a full multiplication table, then you look at row $95$, and find in this row the entry "1". The column of this entry is the inverse element. Btw as others said before, $GF(2^8)$ has 256 elements, not 16.