# How to find multiplicative inverse of a hexadecimal number in the finite field GF(2^8)?

Tags: encryption, aes, finite-field, s-boxes

I am new to cryptography. As I was reading a note regarding S-box construction, I found a step mentioning multiplicative inverse of a number in the finite field GF(2^8). I couldn't understand it!! Can anybody help me by explaining the procedure(step by step) to find multiplicative inverse of a number(say 95 in hex) in the finite field GF(2^8) ?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Can you share your link? Also, I see [Multiplicative inverse in $GF(2^8)$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12956/18298) and [Galois fields in cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2700/18298) as a duplicate to your question.