# multiplicative inverse

Tags: aes

I actually do want to know how to generate the multiplication inverse (M.I) table, I mean the calculation how the M.I been generated.. such as the M.I of 22 is 5A regarding to the table.. Do you know how to calculate M.I how the 22 will become 5A [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplicative inverse in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/multiplicative-inverse-in-operatornamegf28)

Comment: I have a hardware breakdown here: https://github.com/bpdegnan/aes/blob/master/aes-sbox/documentation/aessbox.pdf

Answer (score 1):

`22` is the hex encoding of a binary polynomial $f = x^5 + x$ that is used to represent the element of the AES finite field (the field is defined as $F_{2^8} = GF(2)[x] / p(x)$) where $p(x) = x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ is the reduction polynomial.

Now, we need to find the multiplicative inverse of $f(x)$, i.e. another polynomial $g(x)$ such that
$$
f(x)\cdot g(x) \equiv 1 \pmod{p(x)}
$$
We can do this either by using extended Euclid algorithm for polynomials or using the fact that $f^{-1}(x) = f^{254}(x)$ because of the Little Fermat's Theorem.

Using a computational algebra package like e.g. GP/PARI we can compute

```
p = Mod(1,2)*x^8 + Mod(1,2)*x^4 + Mod(1,2)*x^3 + Mod(1,2)*x + Mod(1,2)
f = Mod(1,2)*x^5 + Mod(1,2)*x
g = Mod(f,p)^-1
```

and we get the result

```
Mod(Mod(1, 2)*x^6 + Mod(1, 2)*x^4 + Mod(1, 2)*x^3 + Mod(1, 2)*x, Mod(1, 2)*x^8 + Mod(1, 2)*x^4 + Mod(1, 2)*x^3 + Mod(1, 2)*x + Mod(1, 2))
```

so we get the reduced polynomial $x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x$ and this encodes as `5A`, the table entry that corresponds to `22`.

The only element that does not have its multiplicative inverse is `00`, so by convention we define that `00` is mapped to `00` again.

Comment: Your method is not effective to generate the table. One can fill it at most $O(n^2)$ field multiplications.

Comment: @kelalaka: Yes, but the question was not about efficiency of the generation algorithm (BTW. for this size of the table asymptotic complexity is just a code golf exercise) but about understanding where do these values come from.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in [Krystian's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/173181), a [former version of this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/77753/3) was wrong. See correction at end of that [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/40140/555) to the [similar question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12956/555) that justified closing the present question.

Comment: You could also call this 'an optimal technique' since you cannot go below linear complexity. One thing that bothers me though is that if we want to consider a general case, you need to find a generator of the group (i.e. how to find `02` in general?). Does it increase the complexity?

Comment: @Kristian : you are totally right, and it happens that `02` is not a generator, thus my code does not even work! Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I was going to ask that. One needs to have a generator at the hand for this to work.

Comment: @Kristian: I hopefully got to the bottom of that, and conclude that finding the generator does not change the complexity: it is asymptotically a single field multiplication per entry in the table. See end of [that answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/40140/555).