# Branchless AES Implementation

Tags: aes, implementation, timing-attack

Imagine a branchless implementation of the AES-128 cipher. Are there any benefits over the implementation that contains branches, other than possible prevention of timing attacks?

Is it even true, that a branchless code can mitigate a timing attack? Are there any other side-channel attacks that are prevented in this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What makes crypto code vulnerable to timing attacks is **data dependent** timing variations. Branching according to a round counter, or to the key size, does not create a vulnerability. Most implementations of AES make no branch according to key or data value, and supressing other branches won't help.

The main source of data-dependent timing variations in AES is in the table lookups for the S-boxes: according to if the entry is in cache, or not, the table fetch will take different time. See for example Daniel J. Bernstein, [*Cache-timing attacks on AES*](http://cr.yp.to/papers.html#cachetiming) (2004) [direct [link to pdf](http://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf)] for more info.

Among ways to make AES code free of any timing dependencies are:

- using [AES-NI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) or other hardware support;
- using a CPU without data cache (and being careful about alignment of the table);
- changing the S-table to a logical expression, possibly using [bitslicing](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30165/555) to regain at least some of the lost speed; unfortunately the AES S-table is rather hard to express  in this way (this has been studied by Joan Boyar and René Peralta, [*A new combinational logic minimization technique with applications to cryptology*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/191) and [*A depth-16 circuit for the AES S-box*](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/332); here are some of their [equations](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/peralta/CircuitStuff/AES_SBox.txt)).

Comment: Is it possible to replace the lookup table (S-box) with a branchless code to eliminate the weakness?

Comment: The link you provided mentions a constant-time AES implementation, I will read the whole PDF later, to understand things more thoroughly. Thanks.