# Is "double-and-add-always" a good mitigation against side channel attacks?

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation, side-channel-attack

In Discrete Log based Cryptography, one of the core operations that one, has to perform is modulo exponentiation. There are many algorithms to choose from, especially, when considering my point of interest "scalar multiplication" of a point (generator) of an Elliptic Curve. The most fundamental algorithm is the double and add method, that runs in **logarithmic** time. But since, the cost of point doubling is different, from the cost of point addition, branching based on secret bits will cause, the secret bit to be leaked to the adversary.
As a mitigation to this, we could do a sort of, dummy addition every iteration and hence the "double and add always" algorithm ! This will camouflage the time difference, I guess. I realize, that there are other algorithms like Montgomery Ladder but Wikipedia says that there exists FLUSH+RELOAD attack on an OpenSSL implementation that uses it.
But are there better algorithms ?
Will there be performance/ security benefits if we migrate to a different coordinate system?

I'm asking this, because I coded an Elliptic Curve implementation from scratch using my custom multiprecision library written in `C` as a learning project. But in my library, I use extended euclidean algorithm for calculating modulo inverses (for performance sake) in $F_{p}$. And also, my multiprecision division algorithm is **not** constant time, it runs in logarithmic time depending on the dividend bit length. These are some bottlenecks that I think is difficult to overcome as far as multiprecision is concerned !  Still my overall working implementation is no way as fast / secure as OpenSSL or other amazing libraries out there and it is not intended to be! But, I would love to know more about secure & fast implementation!

Comment: Which curve are we talking about? Montgomery ladder has a natural side-channel resistance You should give more information about your curve. Also, one needs a code [like](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63783/18298) $Q = (A * S) + (B * S')$. This removes all infomation on the `if/else` $S$ is the true value for if and $A$ and $B$ the `if` and the `else` cases.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [BearSSL's commented implementation](https://bearssl.org/gitweb/?p=BearSSL;a=blob;f=src/ec/ec_prime_i31.c;h=b205f367aebaec00048bec5a68fdc09999a58914;hb=dda1f8a0c46e15b4a235163470ff700b2f13dcc5)

Comment: I wrote a simple answer for a glimpse of if with python for [square-and-multiple](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/75408/18298). Of course, one should not use it. Even when using the C language don't relay on the compiler. You need to check the result or apply a special desing. There was an answer from [@fgrieu about it](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/82095/18298).

Comment: @kelalaka I was referring to the standard curves based on Weierstrass equation $y^2 = x^3 + ax +b$ ...

Comment: Could you give a link of your implementation?

Comment: @kelalaka As mentioned in your links to your excellent answer on constant time exponentiation, to prevent measurement by the adversary. In my implementation, since, we are working with Elliptic curves, I use a similar technique, but instead a two element lookup table: ```EC_POINT * ecp[2] = {&o, &g}; ```, where ```o``` is initialized to a point at infinity. During every iteration of the loop,  we choose what point to add to our result based on ```ecp[AND(k, 1)]``` . But now, I changed everything to do dummy additions! But, I wish I could make those dummy operations, useful!

Comment: If the applicable switch to [Montgomery representation of the curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve#Equivalence_with_Weierstrass_curves)?

Comment: @VivekanandV You're on the right track, but a lookup table means data-dependent memory accesses... Here's [a document](https://summerschool-croatia.cs.ru.nl/2016/slides/PeterSchwabe.pdf) that might help understand how to make a proper implementation.

Comment: @Serpent27 Thankyou very much, for the excellent resource! I thought that a simple table lookup that consists of only two elements will definitely fit into cache memory, that's the reason why I did that table lookup, in the first place!